# Azure:Grouping VMs using Cloud service or Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We are planning to rent have two VMs (one for Web Server and another for Database server) on Azure. I would like to know what would be the best way to communicate Database server from web server.

1. Direct communication using DNS.
2. Keep both the VMs in Cloud service and use host name to communicate.
3. Form a virtual network and use the persistent virtual machine IP address to connect to.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't want to use the Clud Service host name to communicate between the VMs.

If you want to use DNS, you have to provide DNS - you don't need that too.

For that particular scenario, I would recommend something even simpler:

- Put the VMs in the same Cloud service
- Do not go for any Virtual Network or DNS Solutions
- Use VM Name to connect between the machines.

when the VMs are deployed **in the same Cloud Service** and **not in Virtual Network**, Windows Azure provides automatic name discovery. The simplest approach is usually the best.

For more information on name resolution scenarios in Windows Azure, [read this paper](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/).

Comment: Thanks for quick response! What I understood from your response is "Cloud Service" is better option then "Virtual Network" in this case. But what do you mean by "you don't want to use the Clud Service host name to communicate between the VMs.". And i dont have to provide DNS as Azure provide them by default.

Comment: If you place both VMs in the same cloud service, you should be able to directly address each via the VM name. Azure provides DNS resolution within a cloud service automatically.

Comment: You don't want to communicate between via the Cloud Service name, because thus your communication would traverse to border routers of Data Center and come back. That's why just put the VMs in same cloud service and NOT Virtual network. And just use the VM names.

Comment: astaykov, your answer totally make sense. putting VMs in same cloud service is preferred choice. But in case (if my machines are on different cloud service) I have to opt for Virtual network, I could communicate by private IP address. This could be second choice.

Comment: astaykov, you stressed that we should not use hostname but use VM name isntead. I guess both means the same. Your VM is assigned as host name

Comment: Cloud service hostname is `something.cloudapp.net`, while VM Name is `mysuperSQLServer`. These are two absolutely different names! Use only VM Name.